# Passing Filename as a compile flag via VCXproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Is it possible to specify the Filename as a compile time flag in vcxproj. I know the `__FILE__` directive, but I want to provide just the name of the file without the extension to the C file as a define. I can't see how we can provide different flags to different C files included in the ClCompile itemgroup. I tried this, but it didn't work:
`<PreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">SRCFILE=%(Compile.Filename);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>`

Any suggestions on getting this working with both VS 2010 as well as via MSBuild ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to specify a preprocessordefinition per clcompile tag instead..like..

```
<clcompile include="foo.c> <PreprocessorDefinitions>FILENAME="foo"</PreprocessorDefinitions></clcompile>'
```